# Sending attachments in email using nodemailer gives timeout error on netlify lambda function

Tags: reactjs, nodemailer, netlify

I've this issue whenever I try to send  attachments with email in nodemailer it gives me timeout error, since I am using netlify lambda function there is timeout after 10 seconds. However if I try to send the image in body it works.
I am sending URL of image in attachment so I don't think it should give timeout.